# URL is not opened in modal

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make the URL content appear in the modal (let's assume it's [www.google.it](http://www.google.it)), only it doesn't open in the modal.

I tried to use `window.location.href` as shown in the code below, however this site opens in a new page and not in the modal.

Can anyone kindly help me?

```js
// Get the modal
            var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

            // Get the button that opens the modal
            var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

            // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
            var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

            // When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
            btn.onclick = function () {
                modal.style.display = "block";
                window.location.href="www.google.com";
            }

            // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
            span.onclick = function () {
                modal.style.display = "none";
            }

            // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
            window.onclick = function (event) {
                if (event.target == modal) {
                    modal.style.display = "none";
                }
            }
```

```css
.modal {
            display: none;
            /* Hidden by default */
            position: fixed;
            /* Stay in place */
            z-index: 1;
            /* Sit on top */
            padding-top: 100px;
            /* Location of the box */
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            width: 100%;
            /* Full width */
            height: 100%;
            /* Full height */
            overflow: auto;
            /* Enable scroll if needed */
            background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
            /* Fallback color */
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
            /* Black w/ opacity */
        }

        /* Modal Content */
        .modal-content {
            background-color: #fefefe;
            margin: auto;
            padding: 20px;
            border: 1px solid #888;
            width: 80%;
        }

        /* The Close Button */
        .close {
            color: #aaaaaa;
            float: right;
            font-size: 28px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        .close:hover,
        .close:focus {
            color: #000;
            text-decoration: none;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
```

```html
                <!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
                <button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

                <!-- The Modal -->
                <div id="myModal" class="modal">

                    <!-- Modal content -->
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <span class="close">&times;</span>
                        <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
                    </div>

                </div>
```

Comment: You seem to be expecting a regular `div` to act like an `iframe`, most HTML elements can't contain other pages.

Comment: you need an iframe to open a website in another

Comment: Try using location.href instead of window.location.href

Comment: To show content from another URL on your page you could use iframe. If you replace your par with "some text in the modal" with `<iframe id="modal-frame"></iframe>` than you can set an url to this iframe `document.querySelector("#modal-frame").src = url`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I am understanding your question may need to use an iframe in your model to show or open a URL.

`window.location.href="www.google.com";` will redirect your page to the address you mentioned so I comment this line.

You can assign `www.google.com` to iframe src.

```js
// Get the modal
            var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

            // Get the button that opens the modal
            var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

            // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
            var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

            // When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
            btn.onclick = function () {
                modal.style.display = "block";
                //window.location.href="www.google.com";
            }

            // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
            span.onclick = function () {
                modal.style.display = "none";
            }

            // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
            window.onclick = function (event) {
                if (event.target == modal) {
                    modal.style.display = "none";
                }
            }
```

```css
.modal {
            display: none;
            /* Hidden by default */
            position: fixed;
            /* Stay in place */
            z-index: 1;
            /* Sit on top */
            padding-top: 100px;
            /* Location of the box */
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            width: 100%;
            /* Full width */
            height: 100%;
            /* Full height */
            overflow: auto;
            /* Enable scroll if needed */
            background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
            /* Fallback color */
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
            /* Black w/ opacity */
        }

        /* Modal Content */
        .modal-content {
            background-color: #fefefe;
            margin: auto;
            padding: 20px;
            border: 1px solid #888;
            width: 80%;
        }

        /* The Close Button */
        .close {
            color: #aaaaaa;
            float: right;
            font-size: 28px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        .close:hover,
        .close:focus {
            color: #000;
            text-decoration: none;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
```

```html
<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
                <button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

                <!-- The Modal -->
                <div id="myModal" class="modal">

                    <!-- Modal content -->
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <span class="close">&times;</span>
                        <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
                        <iframe src="https://www.w3schools.com" class="url" title="W3Schools Free Online Web Tutorials">
</iframe>
                    </div>

                </div>
```

Comment: Yes `iframe` tag will work.